# Drywall over old roof and shingles

Tags: drywall, garage, construction, storage, fire

We’ve added a garage addition on to our home. The new roofline of the garage encapsulates an existing first floor roof. I’d like to incorporate the area above the existing roof into the new garage attic for additional storage.

[image: garage attic area]

I understand I need fire separation between the garage and existing home and existing attic.

My question is, can I put 5/8” drywall over top of this roof and shingles for a future storage area. It may end up being some stepped shelves to accommodate for the slope, or simply an area for longer items in the garage attic to overhang.

Comment: Remove the shingles...take a couple of them outside and toss them in a bonfire if you fail to grasp what a terrible idea having them inside a building is, not to mention what an abysmal standard of workmanship is in play to have them still there as this is.

Comment: We can see into your other attic (bottom left corner), so I don't think fire behavior is a reason to keep the indoor roof. Also, does that vent on the old roof still work and just dump into the garage? That's going to rust all your tools and cars and whatnot.

Comment: @dandavis that vent is for the old roof, it was not ducted to any appliances or the like. It is simply to vent the attic space itself, this portion of the attic has adequate venting elsewhere.

Comment: @Ecnerwal these are BP Yukon 3 tab shingles with a Class A fire resistance. I’m not concerned about them being a fire risk, especially when considering an additional 5/8 Sheetrock barrier. Also, what is your source? Do you often find yourself burning shingles on a bonfire?

Comment: If you think having a class A rating for catching on fire if burning things fall on them (whoo-hoo, yup, there are rocks on the surface)  doesn't mean you have a lovely mass of tar, which will fuel one heck of a fire inside a building, you're not paying attention to what asphalt shingles are made of.